# grep -m in solaris/sun OS

Tags: solaris, sunos

I searched a lot over google and stackoverflow/serverfault, but I was not able to find a corresponding to "-m" option in the bash shell. I need to fetch only the first result with the grep. Is this possible in the sun-os/solaris?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no -m option to the Solaris grep. The `-m N` switch stops reading a file after `N` lines have been matched. If all you want is N lines of output then you could use

```
grep test file | head -N
```

where `N` is the number of lines of output that you want.

Comment: If you have the SUNWggrp package installed then you can use GNU grep from `/usr/sfw/bin/ggrep`.

Comment: @JamesO'Gorman: ggrep - no wonder I couldn't find it :(

Comment: There is also CSWgrep from OpenCSW. While it installs grep as `/opt/csw/bin/ggrep`, you also have the `/opt/csw/gnu` directory with symlinks, using the original names.

Answer (score 2):

You would need GNU grep to use the -m option.
You could use awk or sed in Solaris instead, if you do not want to use GNU grep:

```
awk '$0 ~ var{print;exit}' var=$string mytextfile
```

Comment: On Solaris 10 you need to use nawk to get this to work.